# Flask not recognising two URL parameters

Tags: python, rest, flask

I'm trying to send two parameters to a URL routed with Flask.

If I do:

```
curl -i http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/journeys/count?startStationName=Hansard%20Mews,%20Shepherds%20Bush&endStationName=Farringdon%20Lane,%20Clerkenwell
```

Then my code which is:

```
@application.route('/api/journeys/count', methods=['GET'])
def journeys():
    print request.args
    startStationName = request.args.get('startStationName')
    endStationName = request.args.get('endStationName')
```

Should print a dict with `startStationName` and `endStationName` defined.

However, instead, only the first parameter seems to be received:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('startStationName', u'Hansard Mews, Shepherds Bush')])
```

Anybody got any idea what I'm doing wrong? I have a feeling there must be some kind of stupid mistake or misunderstanding somewhere but I've been looking for an hour and can't find it.

Comment: You missed the `[1] <process number>` and `[1]+  Exit <exit code>` outputs on the shell..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **shell** interprets the `&` as a [*put the command in the background* character](http://linuxcommand.org/lts0080.php). To prevent this, quote the whole URL:

```
curl -i "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/journeys/count?startStationName=Hansard%20Mews,%20Shepherds%20Bush&endStationName=Farringdon%20Lane,%20Clerkenwell"
```

Comment: Ah brilliant, it works now. Thanks.  Glad I asked now otherwise I would have been scratching my head for a long time.